# Mongoose model dependency injection not working with multiple connection in nestjs

Tags: mongoose, dependency-injection, nestjs

I am using two different mongodb connection in a nestjs application. One with connection name and another without any connection. The one without connection name works perfectly but the other one with connection name doesn't work. I did provided the connection name in InjectModel(), forRootAsync and forFeature but it is still not working.
Here is the schema:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { HydratedDocument, Schema as MongoSchema } from 'mongoose';

export type ActivityLogDocument = HydratedDocument<ActivityLog>;

@Schema({
  timestamps: true,
  versionKey: false,
})
export class ActivityLog {
  @Prop({ nullable: true })
  model: string;

  @Prop({ nullable: true })
  action: string;

  @Prop({ nullable: true })
  operationName: string;

  @Prop({ nullable: true })
  query: string;

  @Prop({ type: MongoSchema.Types.ObjectId, nullable: true })
  documentId: string;

  @Prop({ type: MongoSchema.Types.ObjectId })
  requestedBy: string;

  @Prop({ type: Object, nullable: true })
  difference: object;
}

export const ActivityLogSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(ActivityLog);

// Ghat Activity Log
export type GhatActivityLogDocument = GhatActivityLog & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class GhatActivityLog extends ActivityLog {}

export const GhatActivityLogSchema =
  SchemaFactory.createForClass(GhatActivityLog);

// Counter Activity Log
export type CounterActivityLogDocument = HydratedDocument<CounterActivityLog>;

@Schema({ timestamps: true, versionKey: false })
export class CounterActivityLog extends ActivityLog {}

export const CounterActivityLogSchema =
  SchemaFactory.createForClass(CounterActivityLog);
```

Here is the module:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import {
  CounterActivityLog,
  CounterActivityLogSchema,
  GhatActivityLog,
  GhatActivityLogSchema,
} from '../../repository/schemas/activity-log.schema';
import { ActivityLoggerService } from './activity-logger.service';

export const connectionNameForLogging = 'cats';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      connectionName: connectionNameForLogging,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get('LOG_MONGODB'),
      }),
    }),
    MongooseModule.forFeature(
      [
        {
          name: GhatActivityLog.name,
          schema: GhatActivityLogSchema,
        },
        {
          name: CounterActivityLog.name,
          schema: CounterActivityLogSchema,
        },
      ],
      connectionNameForLogging,
    ),
  ],
  providers: [ActivityLoggerService],
  exports: [ActivityLoggerService],
})
export class ActivityLoggerModule {}
```

And here is the service:

```js
import { Injectable, OnApplicationBootstrap } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { detailedDiff } from 'deep-object-diff';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import * as contextService from 'request-context';
import {
  ActivityLog,
  GhatActivityLog,
} from '../../repository/schemas/activity-log.schema';
import { registeredDBForLogs } from './activity-log-db.config';
import { connectionNameForLogging } from './activity-logger.module';
import { WriteLogInput } from './dtos/writeLogInput';

@Injectable()
export class ActivityLoggerService implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  private models: Record<keyof typeof registeredDBForLogs, Model<ActivityLog>>;

   constructor(
     @InjectModel(GhatActivityLog.name, connectionNameForLogging)
     private ghatLog: Model<GhatActivityLog>,
     @InjectModel(CounterActivityLog.name, connectionNameForLogging)
     private counterLog: Model<CounterActivityLogDocument>,
   ) {}

  public onApplicationBootstrap() {
    console.log('Activity logger is now activated.');
  }
}
```

And it stills gives this error:

```
[Nest] 12372  - 05/18/2023, 4:56:29 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ActivityLoggerService (?). Please make sure that the argument GhatActivityLogModel at index [0] is available in the ActivityLoggerModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is ActivityLoggerModule a valid NestJS module?
- If GhatActivityLogModel is a provider, is it part of the current ActivityLoggerModule?
- If GhatActivityLogModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ActivityLoggerModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing GhatActivityLogModel */ ]
  })

Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ActivityLoggerService (?). Please make sure that the argument GhatActivityLogModel at index [0] is available in the ActivityLoggerModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is ActivityLoggerModule a valid NestJS module?
- If GhatActivityLogModel is a provider, is it part of the current ActivityLoggerModule?
- If GhatActivityLogModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ActivityLoggerModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing GhatActivityLogModel */ ]
  })

    at Injector.lookupComponentInParentModules (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:247:19)
    at Injector.resolveComponentInstance (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:200:33)
    at resolveParam (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:120:38)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Injector.resolveConstructorParams (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:135:27)
    at Injector.loadInstance (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:61:13)
    at Injector.loadProvider (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:88:9)
    at /home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:49:13
    at async Promise.all (index 3)
    at InstanceLoader.createInstancesOfProviders (/home/princebillygk/jatri/new-water-transport/core-water-transport-admin-api/node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/instance-loader.js:48:9)
```

Comment: looks like you're using a connection name but didn't registered that model for such connection. Read the docs

Comment: @MicaelLevi I am using connection name in   MongooseModule.forFeature with collections do I need to do anything else?